# Run query based on value on each row from another query result

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to two tables

- University(UnivId, UnivName)
- Graduate(EmpId, UnivId, GradYear)

I need to create a query that returns result like:

```
UNIVNAME    NUMOFEMPLOYEES
----------- --------------
NYU                      3
UCSB                    10
UCLA                     3
```

which for each university, display the number of employees graduate from the school.

I figured I can get the UnivName:

```
select DISTINCT University.UnivName 
from University, Graduate 
where University.UnivId = Graduate.UnivId;
```

And the number of employees from:

```
select sum(EmpId) from Graduate where UnivId = 'x';
```

I know it's very beginner question, thanks for any help!

Comment: Have you learned INNER JOIN yet?

Comment: You are using a book or tutorial from the 1980s obviously. Get yourself something more up-to-date and forget about the old join sysntax (`from University, Graduate`) and use proper ANSI joins instead (`from University inner join Graduate on University.UnivId=Graduate.UnivId`). It's also a good idea to use alias names when working with multiple tables: (`from University u inner join Graduate g on u.UnivId = g.UnivId`).

Comment: You want an aggregate (count) per group (per university). Have you learnt `GROUP BY`, yet?

Comment: Have you worked with subqueries, yet? The two best solutions would use subqueries: a correclated subquery in `SELECT` or a non-correlated subquery in `FROM`. (An alternative would be to join the tables first and aggregate then. This works here, but is a bad pattern that will fail on more complex queries, so I don't recommend it.)

Comment: use count for empid not sum as it will add the values if it is a number such as empid 1000 and empid 2000 will be 3000 instead of count will result to 2

Answer (score 1):

You JOIN the tables by UnivId and count the number of employees by EmpId

```
SELECT u.UnivName,
       COUNT(g.EmpId) NumOfEmployees
  FROM Univeristy u
  JOIN Graduate g
    ON u.UnivId = g.UnivId
 GROUP BY u.UnivName
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try a LEFT JOIN like below

```
SELECT  
U.UnivName,
ISNULL(Count(1),0)  NUMOFEMPLOYEES
FROM University U LEFT JOIN Graduate G
ON U.UnivId = G.UnivId
GROUP BY U.UnivName;
```